# 400 Bad Request issue in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, urllib, http-status-code-400

When I am running following code in pycharm:

```
import urllib.request
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

I am getting and error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 10:14:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 308
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Process finished with exit code 0**
```

While it works fine when I run the code in terminal/command promt.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your Terminal and Pycharm are not running the code using the same python version, i.e one is running Py2 and the other Py3.

In Pycharm, you can set the desired version like so

[image]

In your terminal verify the version, run `-V` for example if you use `python [path]` then `python -V`.